# Issues setting MIME type in python SSE script

Tags: python, mime-types, server-sent-events

I am trying to implement a server side script in python.
I have tried setting the content-type of the returning data using

```
sys.stdout.write('Content-Type: text/event-stream\r\n\r\n')
```

or

```
print "Content-Type: text/event-stream\n\n"
```

But this does not appear to be getting to the browser, which displays the following error.

"EventSource's response has a MIME type `("text/html"`) that is not "`text/event-stream`". Aborting the connection."

If I replace my server with the original PHP script which uses

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
```

It all works, so I am confident it isn't a path issue.
What would be the correct syntax for setting the content-type in native python (flask etc, unavailable for this)?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
I had the python script as a .php extension which it didn't appear to be happy with.
Once I renamed it to .cgi it all worked happily.